# How to validate an email using Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

I was following this Node.js tutorial but the .validate method gave me an error
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLtyhwFtXQA
Timestamp: 2:07:40

The code:

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    email: Joi.string().trim().email().required(),
    pswd: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required()
  });
  Joi.validate(req.body, schema, (err, result) => {
    if(err) console.log("Error" + err);
    else {
      console.log(result);
      res.send("Successfully Posted Data");
    }
  });
});
```

Error Message: `TypeError: Joi.validate is not a function`

The video is published 2 years ago so Joi might have changed the function for VS Code doesn't show .validate as a function of Joi  either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want something like this
and will assume that `req.body` have the `email` and `pswd` in it

you can read the docs if you want more understanding https://joi.dev/api/

```
const { value, error } = schema.validate(req.body);
if(error) console.log("Error" , error);
else {
      console.log(value);
      res.send("Successfully Posted Data");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your used Joi version, but newest Joi validates via schema not Joi e.g:

```
schema.validate(req.body);
```

Comment: I am using the latest Joi verson(17.3.0) but the video I had taken the code from was 2 years ago so it wasn't working. Thank you for your feedback.